# Spring boot actuator health hangs

Tags: spring-boot-actuator

Why would spring boot health actuator hang ?
I am seeing an issue where the health actuator doesnt respond.

Is it due to unrechability with underlying resources like db / eventhub etc ?

Comment: Hi @schwass, I have exactly the same problem. In my experience as soon as the db comes up again, the health actuator will restart working, giving back the usual "UP" status. But I had the impression the expected behaviour would be for the actuator to return a "DOWN" status or something like that.